# How to convert PyObject to c++ array?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, python-c-api

I am working with python-c binding and I face with following problem. In python class there is a attribute called means which is numpy array of shape (2,3). If pInstance is PyObject* of that class, I wanted to do something like this:

```
PyObject* pMeans = PyObject_GetAttrString(pInstance,"means");
PyArrayObject* contig = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_FromAny(pMeans,
PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_DOUBLE),
    2, 3, NPY_ARRAY_CARRAY, NULL);
```

What I get is ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array. I also tried simple conversion:

```
PyArrayObject* contig = (PyArrayObject*)pMeans;
```

What is the proper eay to do this conversion?

Comment: You have done `import_array()`, right?

Comment: Yes. I found a way by calling `npy_intp ind[2]{0,0};
void* contig = PyArray_GetPtr((PyArrayObject*)pMeans, ind);`